# R: How to aggregate rows of dfs in a list (containing empty dfs)?

Tags: r, list, aggregate

I want to aggregate all rows of data frames within a list which have the same character in a column. For this I used

```
lapply(lst, function(x) aggregate(Value ~ Area, x, sum))
```

which works fine. However, I get also empty dfs in my list (which I need, so I cannot drop them) and I get an error:

```
Error in aggregate.data.frame(mf[1L], mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate
```

Is there a way to overcome this error? Thanks. Below a small example:

```
lst <- list("111.2012"=data.frame("Area"=character(0), "Value"=numeric(0)),
            "112.2012"=data.frame("Area"=c("a","b","b","a"), "Value"=c(1,5,3,2)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst <- list("111.2012"=data.frame("Area"=character(0), "Value"=numeric(0)),
            "112.2012"=data.frame("Area"=c("a","b","b","a"), "Value"=c(1,5,3,2)))


lapply(lst, function(x) if (nrow(x)) aggregate(Value ~ Area, x, sum) else x)
```

Output

```
$`111.2012`
[1] Area  Value
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$`112.2012`
  Area Value
1    a     3
2    b     8
```

Comment: Consider adding `else x` to the anonymous function so that "empty" list elements are returned as is (i.e. with column names but 0 rows).

Comment: @docendodiscimus neat suggestion, kudos